# Affine transformation

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be sets. Let $n_1$ be the cardinality of $S_1$ and $n_2$ be the cardinality of $S_2$. I assume that $n_1$ and $n_2$ are finite. Let $e$ be a function that maps members of $S_1$ and $S_2$ to real numbers.
Assume that we have:

$(1/n_1) \sum\limits_{x_i \in S_1} e(x_i) \geq (1/n_2) \sum\limits_{x_i \in S_2} e(x_i)$.

Let $e'$ be a affine transformation of $e$, i.e., we have $e'(x) = ke(x) + l$, where $k$ is positive.

Given this, I know that it is guaranteed that:

$(1/n_1) \sum\limits_{x_i \in S_1} e'(x_i) \geq (1/n_2) \sum\limits_{x_i \in S_2} e'(x_i)$

That is, affine transformations are guaranteed to preserve inequalities between the average values assigned to finite sets by some function $e$.

Question: Is there a class of transformations that isn't a subclass of affine transformations for which this same property is true?

Comment: The question doesn't look very understandable to me, maybe you should define $e, x_i$ and $S_1, S_2$.

Comment: Tried to clear some things up.

Comment: Ok, now it's clearer. I bet that the answer is 'no', that is that only affine transformations do the job you are asking for, but don't trust this intuition too much!

Comment: I think so as well, but can't quite see how to prove it.