# Do only affine transformations preserve mid-points?

Tags: linear-algebra

An affine transformation on $\mathbb{R}$ preserves mid-points. That is, if $f$ is affine then for any $x, z, q$, if $x$ is the mid-point of $[z, q]$, then $f(x)$ is the mid-point of $[f(z), f(q)]$.

Question: Are there any non-affine transformations on $\mathbb{R}$ with this same property? Or is it only affine transformations that preserve mid-points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the title question is "no" and the answer to the body question is "yes." $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, and any $\mathbb{Q}$-linear function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (that is, a solution to the [Cauchy functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)) preserves midpoints. Most such functions are not $\mathbb{R}$-affine.

Comment: Thanks. A related question: Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be sets. Let $n_1$ be the cardinality of $S_1$ and $n_2$ be the cardinality of $S_2$. I assume that $n_1$ and $n_2$ are finite. Let $e$ be a function that maps members of $S_1$ and $S_2$ to real numbers.
Assume that we have:

$(1/n_1) \sum\limits_{x_i \in S_1} e(x_i) \geq (1/n_2) \sum\limits_{x_i \in S_2} e(x_i)$.

Let $e'$ be a affine transformation of $e$, i.e., we have $e'(x) = ke(x) + l$, where $k$ is positive.

Given this, I know that it is guaranteed that: 

$(1/n_1) \sum\limits_{x_i \in S_1} e'(x_i) \geq (1/n_2) \sum\limits_{x_i \in S_2} e

Comment: That is, affine transformations are guaranteed to preserve inequalities between the average values assigned to finite sets by some function $e$.

Question: Is there a class of transformations that isn't a subclass of affine transformations for which this same property is true?

Comment: @mike: it would be better for you to ask this as a separate question.

Comment: I did, but unfortunately didn't get a response. It's under the title `Affine Transformations'

Comment: Here's the link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248344/affine-transformation

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. If $f$ preserves midpoints, it must be midpoint convex. However, there are examples of midpoint-convex functions that are not convex (and hence not affine). A classical one is this. Take a Hamel basis $\cal B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ (as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$). Let $u$ be a nonzero elements in $\cal B$. For any real number $x$, define $f(x)=q_u$ whenever $x=\sum_{r\in{\cal B}}q_r r$ is the unique representation of $x$ as linear combination of "vectors" in $\cal B$. Then $f$ is a linear function on the *vector space* $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (hence midpoint preserving). However, it is not an affine function on the field $\mathbb{R}$: we have $f(0)=0$ and $f(u)=1$, but for every $v\in{\cal B}\setminus\{0,u\}$, we also have $f(v)=0$.

That said, practically, [most convex functions are midpoint convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties).